# Existance of a solution for ODE in Complex field?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I have been searching for a proof about the (local?) existence and uniqueness( analogous to Picard's theorem ) of the ODE in Complex field rather than real. Meaning $f'(z) = U(z,f(z))$ for $C^{\infty}$ function $U: \mathbb{C}^{2} \to \mathbb{C}$. From what I have found on the web, the theorem I might be searching for is Cauchy-Kowalevski's. However, I could not find a textbook proof of the theorem anywhere. I think that the theorem is important enough so that it should have a proof in some textbooks. Could you give me a reference book on this topic?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure the Picard-Lindelof theorem holds for complex functions. [Malmquist's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malmquist%27s_theorem) is briefly covered on Wikipedia, but without proof.